# Merge if condition met on both data sets

Tags: sas

I have two datasets and only want them to merge if the meet a certain condition within both sets.

The code below is not correct.

```
data cohrt2_base_pre_&m2. cohrt2_base_a4lmig_&m2.;
     length Base_indicator_&m2. $20.;
     merge if pre_cb_&m3. = pre_cb_&m4. then do;
          custon.cohrt_base_pre_&m1. (in=a)
          VALIAT_B.STATPST_M1_&m2. (in=b drop=base
                                    (rename=(priceplan=Pre_priceplan_&m4.)));

    by kit_sim msisdn
    end;
```

Answer (score 1):

PROC SQL can do this :

```
proc sql ;
  create table want (drop=base) as
  select a.*, b.*, b.priceplan as pre_priceplan_&m4
  from custon.cohrt_base_pre_&m1 a
       inner join
       VALIAT_B.STATPST_M1_&m2 b on a.kit_sim = b.kit_sim
                                and a.msisdn = b.msisdn
                                and pre_cb_&m3 = pre_cb_&m4 ;
quit ;
```

Comment: if i want to add the following..what would the code look like in sql?                     
 if a and b then  Base_indicator_&m2.='Constant';
 if a and not b then  Base_indicator_&m2.='Churn';
 if b and not a then  Base_indicator_&m2.='Acquisition';
   
    if pre_cb_&m3. eq post_cb_&m4. then output cohrt2_base_a4lmig_&m2.;

Answer (score 0):

So pre_cb_&m3 and pre_cb&m4 exist in both datasets, and you want to filter them?  If so, then you can add a where option, something like (untested):

```
data cohrt2_base_pre_&m2.
     cohrt2_base_a4lmig_&m2.
;
     length Base_indicator_&m2. $20.;
     merge 
          custon.cohrt_base_pre_&m1. (where=(pre_cb_&m3. = pre_cb_&m4.)
                                      in=a
                                      )
          VALIAT_B.STATPST_M1_&m2.   (where=(pre_cb_&m3. = pre_cb_&m4.) 
                                      drop=base
                                      rename=(priceplan=Pre_priceplan_&m4.)
                                      in=b
                                      );

    by kit_sim msisdn;
run;
```

If the variables do exist in both datasets, they would **collide in the merge**, which is usually a bad idea.  Another idea would be to create a view of each dataset which does the subsetting, then merge the two views.  That should allow you to avoid the collision.